# How to disable the authentication prompt in chrome when using selenium chrome web driver

Tags: java, google-chrome, security, selenium, authentication

I have a site https://www.example1.com
Through selenium I need to visit the site and check for something.
The site has SSO, and I have access to the site.

However, when i try visiting the through selenium, I get automatically redirected to a different link, and I am prompted to enter credentials in an alert dialog box.

Now how do I automatically pass my credentials through code? I have tried sending the credentials in the following manner but it did not work.

https://username:password@example1.com

Another point to note is that, when i visit the site manually through chrome, the site opens up and no authentication prompt pops up.

Comment: can you give us more information as to how you us selenium?

Comment: does the popup still show if you try username:password@url? Because I had such a site and it worked nicely with the credentials in the url.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide username and password on alert pop up then you can try following code:

```
alert.sendKeys("UserName");
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
alert.sendKeys("Password");
alert.accept();
```